# How To Make Collection of Locale.getISOCountries()

Tags: java

I want to put all ISO country codes, which is the output of `Locale.getISOCountries()`,  as a collection of `CountryCode`, and it's written like this:

```
public class CountryCodes {
  public static final CountryCode GLOBAL = CountryCode.of("GL");

  public static final PCollection<String> ALL = 
        OrderedPSet.from(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()));
}
```

This works, I have list of country codes in `ALL`, but I want `ALL` to be a `CountryCode` just like `GLOBAL`, not `String`. What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: What you ask is doable, although you have to submit your code for `CountryCode` and `OrderedPSet` classes in order to figure out the logic before trying to provide any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
OrderedPSet.from(
  Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOContries())
    .stream()
    .map(CountryCode::of)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
 )
```

I haven't tried the code but the main idea is that you should get the `List` you build with `Arrays.asList` and `map` over each item on the list with a function that converts a `String` into a `CountryCode`. That function is `CountryCode::of`.

Comment: Just added `()` to `toList`, and it worked like a charm :)